# Is MySQL Cluster appropriate for a small, low-volume multi-homed system?

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster, multi-homed

I'd like to multi-home a proprietary web-based application for a relatively small user base with modest dataset size.  Scalability is not as much of a concern as extremely high availability.  The system has extremely basic architecture: PHP running on a single Linux VPS tapping into a standard MySQL server.

I'm thinking to use multiple VPS's in geographically distinct datacenters such that if a user has problems connecting to one server location, they can try another (I have separate ideas on how to semi-automate the failover, and potentially georoute, but that's another issue).  PHP application code and other files would be rsynced; however, I haven't yet resolved how to sync the databases... is it reasonable to use MySQL Cluster for this?

If one node goes down, the others must continue working.  When a node comes back up, it should automatically get back in sync.  Given that there would be WAN-type latency between datacenters, write speed cannot be dependent on intra-cluster connectivity.  Data consistency is desirable but not the overriding priority.  System simplicity is important--I can't afford to spend the next month figuring out the nuances of the database.

If MySQL Cluster is not appropriate for this, then what are some other alternatives to consider?

Comment: I'd like to leave this open a little longer before accepting an answer, to see what other replies might come in.  BTW- if you could mention any real-world experience you have with a suggested approach, that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simpler solution, in my opinion, is a MySQL master-master replication configuration where  both sites push queries to the other and execute them.  A to-the-point howto can be found here:

http://www.howtoforge.com/mysql_master_master_replication

If you have an existing dataset, you can use `mysqldump` to export the database prior to performing these steps, so that it can be inserted on the slave before the configuration is done.  Just be sure to get the master_log_position as you do the export so you know where to catch up from.  I highly recommend building a dev environment to work on so that you can learn how it all works.

Comment: And for more than two servers this can be expanded to master/master/.../master, etc., with the last one linking back to the first.

Comment: sorry for the delay in accepting.  I only now had a chance to try it out, and so far so good!

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Cluster generally is not suitable for web applications.

It's kind of an exotic solution but check out [Galera](http://www.codership.com/products/galera_replication)

I remember seeing somewhere that they said WAN replication is possible.

There is also [Tungsten Enterprise](http://www.continuent.com/solutions/tungsten-enterprise).

Galera is synchronous replication, whereas Tungsten is asynchronous.

Cheers